# Why can the type of the parameter for InsertOnSubmit not be inferred from the usage?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables and I am building a function to insert the data into two different tables within one function.

```
_dc.tblCarDetails.InsertOnSubmit(tblCarDetail);
_dc.tblCarConditions.InsertAllOnSubmit(tblCarCondition);
```

This gives the following error:

> the type arguments for method `system.data.linq.table<wcfService1.tblCarCondition.InsertOnSubmit<TSubEntity>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSubEntity>)` cannot be inferred from the usage.Try specifying the type arguments explicityly.

Why can the type not be inferred? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Normally, it can be inferred. Maybe the type of the function argument is incompatible.

Comment: Is `tblCarCondition` an `IEnumerable`? Doesn't sound so.

Comment: no its not ienumerable

Comment: Well, it should be if you want to use if with `InsertAllOnSubmit`. Unless you have another implementation. If you want to insert a single element, use `InsertOnSubmit()`.

Comment: thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write your code as follow

```
_dc.tblCarDetails.InsertOnSubmit(tblCarDetail);
_dc.tblCarConditions.InsertOnSubmit(tblCarCondition);
```

You have a mistake in

```
InsertAllOnSubmit
```

just change it as

```
InsertOnSubmit
```